# How do I generate datetime values to fill data gaps

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to fill gaps in weather station data sheets, the problem is that my sheets dont have empty cells for places where the data is missing, it just jumps from say 2023-04-07 10:30 to 2023-04-07 16:30. I originally had excel files but I have imported this data to oracle sql data base and I am trying to fill the values using sql developer.

Here's the sql code I ran,

```sql
WITH DateSequence AS (
    SELECT
        TRUNC(MIN(Time), 'HH24') + (LEVEL - 1) / 48 AS generated_datetime
    FROM
        WeatherData
    CONNECT BY
        LEVEL <= (TRUNC(MAX(Time), 'HH24') - TRUNC(MIN(Time), 'HH24')) * 48 + 1
)
SELECT
    ds.generated_datetime
FROM
    DateSequence ds
LEFT JOIN
    WeatherData wd  -- Corrected alias here
ON
    ds.generated_datetime = wd.Time  -- Corrected alias here
WHERE
    wd.Time IS NULL
ORDER BY
    ds.generated_datetime;
```

Is there any simpler way to do this using PowerBI in excel? or a simpler query in sql?

Answer (score 3):

This query will first generate a sequence of dates and times, starting at the minimum time in your data set and ending at the maximum time. It will then join this sequence to your data set, using the time column as the join condition. For any rows in the sequence that do not have a corresponding row in the data set, the temperature and humidity columns will be set to 0. The results of the query will be ordered by the time column.

```
SELECT
  generated_datetime AS time,
  CASE
    WHEN wd.temperature IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE wd.temperature
  END AS temperature,
  CASE
    WHEN wd.humidity IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE wd.humidity
  END AS humidity,
  ...
FROM (
  SELECT
    TRUNC(MIN(time), 'HH24') + (LEVEL - 1) / 48 AS generated_datetime
  FROM weather_data
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (TRUNC(MAX(time), 'HH24') - TRUNC(MIN(time), 'HH24')) * 48 + 1
) ds
LEFT JOIN weather_data wd
ON ds.generated_datetime = wd.time
ORDER BY ds.generated_datetime;
```

***Excel Approach***

You can also use Power Query (In Excel or Power BI) to fill the gaps in your data. To do this, you can use the following steps:

Create a new measure in Power BI by clicking on the "New Measure" button in the "Measures" pane.
In the "Formula Editor" window, enter the following formula:

```
= IF(ISBLANK([Time]), 0, [Time])
```

1. Click on the "OK" button to save the measure.
2. Create a new table or chart in Power BI and add the following fields:
3. Time Temperature Humidity
4. New measure (created in step 2)

Change the measure aggregation to "Average".
This will create a table or chart that shows the average temperature and humidity for each time period, even if there are gaps in the data.

Comment: Your query outputs `ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jg-Lp_pj)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, use a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN` to return all the values, including the missing values:

```sql
WITH DateSequence (time) AS (
  SELECT min_time + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
  FROM   (
    SELECT TRUNC(MIN(Time), 'HH24') AS min_time,
           TRUNC(MAX(Time), 'HH24') As max_time
    FROM   WeatherData
  )
  CONNECT BY min_time + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '30' MINUTE <= max_time
)
SELECT wd.station_id,
       ds.time,
       wd.temperature,
       wd.windspeed,
       wd.rainfall
FROM   DateSequence ds
       LEFT JOIN WeatherData wd
       PARTITION BY (wd.station_id)
       ON ds.time = wd.Time;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE WeatherData (station_id, time, temperature, windspeed, rainfall) AS
  SELECT 1, DATE '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL '7:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 15,  5,  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL '7:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, 16,  4,  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL '9:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 17,  3,  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL '7:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 14, 10, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL '8:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, 19,  6, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, DATE '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL '8:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 12, 30,  8 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| STATION_ID | TIME | TEMPERATURE | WINDSPEED | RAINFALL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1970-01-01 07:00:00 | 15 | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | 1970-01-01 07:30:00 | 16 | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 1970-01-01 08:00:00 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 1 | 1970-01-01 08:30:00 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 1 | 1970-01-01 09:00:00 | 17 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 1970-01-01 07:00:00 | 14 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 1970-01-01 07:30:00 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | 1970-01-01 08:00:00 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | 1970-01-01 08:30:00 | 19 | 6 | 20 |
| 2 | 1970-01-01 09:00:00 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | 1970-01-01 07:00:00 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | 1970-01-01 07:30:00 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | 1970-01-01 08:00:00 | 12 | 30 | 8 |
| 3 | 1970-01-01 08:30:00 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | 1970-01-01 09:00:00 | *null* | *null* | *null* |

---

If you want to replace the missing values with `0` then use `COALESCE`:

```sql
WITH DateSequence (time) AS (
  SELECT min_time + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
  FROM   (
    SELECT TRUNC(MIN(Time), 'HH24') AS min_time,
           TRUNC(MAX(Time), 'HH24') As max_time
    FROM   WeatherData
  )
  CONNECT BY min_time + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '30' MINUTE <= max_time
)
SELECT wd.station_id,
       ds.time,
       COALESCE(wd.temperature, 0) AS temperature,
       COALESCE(wd.windspeed, 0) AS windspeed,
       COALESCE(wd.rainfall, 0) AS rainfall
FROM   DateSequence ds
       LEFT JOIN WeatherData wd
       PARTITION BY (wd.station_id)
       ON ds.time = wd.Time;
```

Which outputs:

| STATION_ID | TIME | TEMPERATURE | WINDSPEED | RAINFALL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1970-01-01 07:00:00 | 15 | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | 1970-01-01 07:30:00 | 16 | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 1970-01-01 08:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1970-01-01 08:30:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1970-01-01 09:00:00 | 17 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 1970-01-01 07:00:00 | 14 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 1970-01-01 07:30:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1970-01-01 08:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1970-01-01 08:30:00 | 19 | 6 | 20 |
| 2 | 1970-01-01 09:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1970-01-01 07:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1970-01-01 07:30:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1970-01-01 08:00:00 | 12 | 30 | 8 |
| 3 | 1970-01-01 08:30:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1970-01-01 09:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5yAey1Yo)